# How can I include/save info for another class in UML document creation?

Tags: uml, software-design

I'm struggling to create this UML document properly. Here are my questions:

1. After the costumer enters details, the Arragement class will calculate the cost and distance, accordingly.

> *Would it be okay to
>   use calCostAndDis(Custumer) : (int) for this?*

2. When I use an arrow and say "has access to", I want the variables in one class to be accessible by the other class, meaning the other class contains the those variables.
   For example, after a customer makes an order, the info will be saved to the CarsRecord class. So that later we can check the info in the record.

> *How can I express it
>   in UML notation?*

3. If I want the SystemRecord to contain both Carsrecord and ChauffeursRecord,(meaning it has access to both of them as they are part of the system record)

> *Does my graph express
>   this idea correctly?*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that should be fine.
2. Just draw an association between both classes, place an association role (a name) towards the class whose attributes you need and mark them as public (plus sign in front).

[image]

3. No, this is not correct (it's a generalization). Replace the triangles with filled diamonds which will make them composite aggregations.

N.B.:

- Spelling: Customer
- start each attribute with a lower case char
- The overall design needs quite some rework